# jquery weekcalendar.js misalignment issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-week-calendar

In jquery.weekcalendar.js if i zoom in and zoom out there is a misalignment happening between the time slots and hours header like in the image below.

[image]

In browsers like chrome, safari and firefox i am getting this issue. How can i make it aligned when it is zoomed in or out?

Comment: Is this on all browsers or only specific ones? Zooming is behaving akward in most browsers.

Comment: I have checked in chrome and firefox. This misalignment happens there

Comment: You should edit that info into your question. That is important for people to know.

Comment: It could help if you can add an minimal example of html and script that demo's the behavior so people can experiment.

Comment: its a plugin . Got it from here https://github.com/teamdf/jquery-calendar

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45474/discussion-between-user1-and-rene)

Comment: @User1 Even if I would like to help here , I'm simply unable to reproduce this issue. Not because it can't be there, but because this is a very bad question, it does not even include a link to where to test that. If you expect an answer, please read the FAQ and respect the guidelines. At least, provide a minimal example. I unsuccessfully tested with http://opensource.teamdf.com/calendar/examples/week.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do anything in this condition unless you want to edit the sources for weekcalendar.js. It would be better to post this problem here: https://github.com/themouette/jquery-week-calendar/issues and get the programmer to fix it. That way all will benefit from the change.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a style to fix that. This works for me:

```
*,
*:before,
*:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box !important;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box !important;
    box-sizing: content-box !important;
}
```